# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column with datatables

Tags: mysql, datatables, laravel-5.3

i'm using laravel 5.3

i have 2 tables (users and jadwals), when i want to display table jadwals with datatables i got this error message:

### SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jadwals.users_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `jadwals` left join `users` on `jadwals`.`users_id` = `users`.`id` order by `users`.`name` asc limit 10 offset 0)

table users

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->bigInteger('nimnip')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
```

table jadwals

```
Schema::create('jadwals', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('kegiatan');
        $table->integer('ruangan_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('jam_mulai_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('jam_selesai_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('ruangan_id')->references('id')->on('ruangans')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('jam_mulai_id')->references('id')->on('jams')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('jam_selesai_id')->references('id')->on('jams')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

model user

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'nimnip', 'email', 'password',
];

public function jadwals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Jadwal');
}

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

model jadwal

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function ruangans()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ruangan');
}

public function jams()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Jam');
}
```

JadwalsController

```
    class JadwalsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request, Builder $htmlBuilder)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $jadwals = Jadwal::with('users', 'ruangans', 'jams');
            return Datatables::of($jadwals)
                ->addColumn('action', function($jadwal){
                    return view('datatable._action', [
                        'model'             =>  $jadwal,
                        'form_url'          =>  route('jadwals.destroy', $jadwal->id),
                        'edit_url'          =>  route('jadwals.edit', $jadwal->id),
                        'confirm_message'   =>  'yakin mau menghapus ' . $jadwal->kegiatan . '?'
                        ]);
                })->make(true);
        }

        $html = $htmlBuilder
            ->addColumn(['data' => 'users.name',        'name' => 'users.name',         'title' => 'Nama Peminjam'])
            ->addColumn(['data' => 'kegiatan',          'name' => 'kegiatan',           'title' => 'Kegiatan'])
            ->addColumn(['data' => 'ruangans.ruangan',  'name' => 'ruangan.ruangan',   'title' => 'Ruangan'])
            ->addColumn(['data' => 'jams.jam',          'name' => 'jam.jam',           'title' => 'Jam Mulai'])
            ->addColumn(['data' => 'jams.jam',          'name' => 'jam.jam',           'title' => 'Jam Selesai'])
            ->addColumn(['data' => 'action', 'name' => 'action', 'title'=>'', 'orderable'=>false, 'searchable'=>false]);

            return view('jadwals.index')->with(compact('html'));
    }
```

what is the problem here?

Comment: where is your query sql?

Comment: you see that your column is user_id and you put in the query users_id? user not users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your able of users have a name 'users'. Laravel search a column that have users_id name, because table name is 'users'. 
Change this functions: users on Jawals model and jadwals on users model.
with:

on User model:

```
public function jadwals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Jadwal', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

On Jadwals model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These lines indicate that the table contains a column name `user_id`

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                 ^^^^^^^

$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
                 ^^^^^^^
```

The SQL statement being executed is referencing a column name `users_id` which doesn't appear in the table definition:

```
select *
  from `jadwals`
  left
  join `users`
    on `jadwals`.`users_id` = `users`.`id`
                  ^^^^^^^^
 order by `users`.`name` asc
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before your jadwals table does not have column user**s**, it has column user. So this should work ok:

```
SELECT * FROM jadwals 
LEFT JOIN users 
  ON jadwals.user_id = users.id 
ORDER BY users.name ASC 
LIMIT 10 
OFFSET  0
```